# Closing Window's from upon switching to another or vice versa

Tags: vb.net, winforms, formclosing

I wrote a Window Application which has two different parent-forms (form1, and form2). Each form has several child forms. After I login it opens form1. Now I have a button (called switch to form2) on form1, which switch to form2. Now I need to close form1 after opening form2. I need to same thing from form2 to form1.

What would be the best way to handle this.

I tried something like below by adding this code to close form under form load of each forms, but I am getting the following exception.

```
 A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
```

Can you please suggest me to handle this problem?

**Form 1**

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
 For Each frm As Form In Application.OpenForms
   If frm.Name.ToLower = "form2" Then
      frm.Close()
   End If
 Next
End Sub
```

**Form 2**

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
 For Each frm As Form In Application.OpenForms
   If frm.Name.ToLower = "form1" Then
      frm.Close()
   End If
 Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: Oh and shouldn't it be `frm.Name.ToLower()` (notice the parantheses)? I might be wrong, I'm really not familiar with the vb syntax.

Comment: A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Comment: Use the little edit link under your question to edit this exception into your question - this is some valuable information on the route to solve your problem!

Comment: As the error says, you cannot alter a collection *while* you are enumerating it.  When you close the form, the `OpenForms` colelction is changed

Comment: Why not just close the current form in your switch button event handler?  You may need to change the the Application Shutdown Mode from "when startup form closes" to "when last form closes" in Project Menu->Project Properties->Application Tab.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are responsible for creating your forms.
If so, I would overload the constructor of each of the forms to take a parameter of the type of the other form and close it there.
For your `Form1` it would be :

```
Public Sub New(form2 As Form2)
  InitializeComponent()
  'and the rest of your initialization code

  If form2 IsNot Nothing Then
    form2.Close()
  End If
End Sub
```

Vice versa for the constructor of `Form2`.

It doesn't even have to be so specialized like above. You could always generalize it to take an object of the type `Form` as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

why not use Form1.Hide()?

that way you can still access the other form while it is not visible.

I hope this helps.